# github git-credential: "erase" operation not supported

Tags: github-cli

I have some trouble with the github repository I am working on.
I just realised I am 3 commits ahead of main and wanted to push, but the terminal prompted the following:

```
git push
gh auth git-credential: "erase" operation not supported
remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/name/project/'
```

Has anyone encountered this before and can help?

Many thanks

Comment: This appears to be a problem or bug with the `gh` command. I updated your tags, but it's probably best to just report this directly to the `gh` command maintainers.

Comment: Where are you running this command? My guess is that the error message is about terminal capabilities - that is, the ability of the command line environment you're in to hide characters typed as part of a password.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to re-authenticate with GitHub. Run the following command and follow the prompts.

```
gh auth login
```

Answer (score 10):

The accepted answer didn't work for me.

I had to do `gh auth refresh` instead.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately both `gh auth login` and `gh auth refresh` don't work for me.   `gh auth status` shows that I'm logged in.

This came up for me on `git pull` and it's only happening on one repository out of many. I also haven't touched this repository for at least 3 months, so I deleted the whole folder from my local and cloned the repo again.

This fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Do you use tokens? Isn't it a matter of rights associated to this token? (you have boxes to check)

Comment: I was using SSH login through gh auth login, not token.  I ruled out authorization issue because there was no different authorization for separate repositories.  I was able to access the repo in github as well as others.

After deleting the folder and cloning the repo, I was able to work normally, further ruling out auth issue.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, none of the other answers seemed to work.

My repo was last accessed by me 3 months ago, and since then, my Personal Access Token (PAT) expired.
I also realized that my PAT was hard-coded into one of the files. So, in my case, I fixed it by following procedure:

1. I created a new PAT by logging into Github in browser and going to `Settings > Developer Settings > Personal access tokens > Tokens (classic)` and using the `Generate new token` button.
2. I copied the generated token.
3. In my local directory, I went to the following file in my git synced folder: `.git/config`.
4. Under `[remote "origin"]`, the url was something like: `https://username:old_PAT@github.com/username/repo-name.git`. I modified it by changing `old_PAT` to `new_PAT` and saving the file.
5. Then, running `git pull origin main` in Terminal worked for me.

Comment: This is a better solution for me since I need permanent access on a specific user, for automated actions, and I'm unsure if the `git auth` solution is permanent

Answer (score 1):

**Just in case it helps anybody.**

I have faced the same problem while executing a `git push`.

This situation has been this:

- I use the same laptop for my usual day-work and my personal work. I have separate github accounts (usernames, emails etc.) for each of these two.
- I write some code. I want to check in to a repository in my personal github.com account.
- I do necessary housekeeping (*commit*, *status*, *log* etc.), to ensure that I am ready to push to my personal github account.
- I do a `git push`, and I am reprimanded:

> remote: Permission to {my personal github username}/-------.git denied to
> {my workplace github username}.
>
> fatal: unable to access
> 'https://github.com/{my personal github username}/-------.git/'': The
> requested URL returned error: 403

From the same laptop, I submit code my workplace github too, and for good reasons, that username is the default on my laptop. So, I understand that I have to override that.

After some exploration - including visiting this page on Stackoverflow - and trying out a few things, I have taken the following steps:

**First**, use the `gh`, the github CLI tool (version 1.9.2 (2021-04-20), on Ubuntu 22.10), to check which user's credentials is being taken up by git, at the moment:

```
nirmalya@bluewhale:attempt_2_tac$ gh auth status
github.com
  ✓ Logged in to github.com as {my workplace github username} (/home/nirmalya/.config/gh/hosts.yml)
  ✓ Git operations for github.com configured to use https protocol.
  ✓ Token: *******************
```

The output underscores the reason behind that dour response to my `git push` earlier.

**Second**, ensure that this session is brought down.

```
nirmalya@bluewhale:attempt_2_tac$ gh auth logout
? Are you sure you want to log out of github.com account '{my workplace github username}'? Yes /* <- default response */
✓ Logged out of github.com account '{my workplace github username}'
```

I am in the clear. I must be able to push now! Nah!

```
nirmalya@bluewhale:attempt_2_tac$ git push
Username for 'https://github.com': {my personal github username}
Password for 'https://{my personal github username}@github.com': /* I type in the password */
gh auth git-credential: "erase" operation not supported
remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021.
remote: Please see https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/about-remote-repositories#cloning-with-https-urls for information on currently recommended modes of authentication.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/{my personal github username}/whatever.git/
```

**Third**, I set myself up for a fresh login:

```
nirmalya@bluewhale:attempt_2_tac$ gh auth login
? What account do you want to log into? GitHub.com
? What is your preferred protocol for Git operations? HTTPS
? How would you like to authenticate GitHub CLI? Login with a web browser

! First copy your one-time code: D823-F390
- Press Enter to open github.com in your browser... 
Opening in existing browser session. 
/* at this point I move to browser and log in using my usual 2FA authentication scheme */
✓ Authentication complete. Press Enter to continue...

- gh config set -h github.com git_protocol https
✓ Configured git protocol
✓ Logged in as {my prsonal github username}
```

**Now**, I am all set to push to github, it seems:

```
nirmalya@bluewhale:attempt_2_tac$ git push
Enumerating objects: 11, done.
Counting objects: 100% (11/11), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (8/8), done.
Writing objects: 100% (9/9), 1.46 KiB | 1.46 MiB/s, done.
Total 9 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (1/1), done.
To https://github.com/{my personal github username}/whatever.git
   aa6dc4f..b04f5e7  main -> main
```

Phew! :-)

Hopefully, this will save someone's time.